# Clearing multiple prompts it sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I have started to play with sqlite3, and using .prompt command for creating multiple prompts, but I can't clear them. I mean to return back to normal "sqlite3>" prompt, except for exiting sqlite3 and starting all over again. Google does not seem to know how xD. I'm using win7/64bit, version SQLite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompts are initialized only when `sqlite3` is started, and overwritten by the `.prompt` command.

To go back to the normal prompts, overwrite them with the original values:

```
.prompt "sqlite> " "   ...> "
```